# Change language be changed in static website without php possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm considering adding multiple languages to my website and looking for ideas on how to possibly implement. My website is static however and I'm curious if there is a way without PHP to allow the website to flip between different languages via a button. I've seen various questions asking how to do this task using PHP, however can it be done without PHP?

For example, can a static website switch between different languages in the same way that a webpage can easily swap stylesheets using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods you can use. One way is to adapt the script used here:

[How do I toggle multiple divs individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038311/how-do-i-toggle-multiple-divs-individually/23038486#23038486)

You can place all the translated text in one page but hide them in separate divs such that only one div shows. Then you can hook button click events to change the visible div whose language you would like to show.

An alternative is to implement AJAX calls to retrieve different html pages depending on the selected language.